# Como usar arquivos .h na linguagem c?

Tags: c

Gostaria de saber qual o uso mais recomendado dos arquivos `*.h`? Pois não sei se posso usa-los só para colocar o protótipo das funções ou a função por completo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A maioria dos arquivos .h, servem apenas para fazer referencia a um método que está em um arquivo .c, .a , .so, .o ou .dll, mais isso não o impede de colocar as funcionalidades dentro deles, só não é semanticamente correto. um exemplo para uso é assim...

file.h

```
#ifndef  FILE_H
#define  FILE_H

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <malloc.h>
    #include <stdarg.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <string.h>

    void method_01(void);
    int method_02(int , int);
    const char * method_return_string();

#endif  /*FILE_H*/
```

file.c

```
#include "file.h"

void method_01(void){
    puts("method called...");
}

int method_02(int x, int y){
    return x+y;
}

const char method_return_string(){
    char *c = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*60);
    strcat(c,"my text");

    return c;
}
```

Comment: "mais isso não o impede de colocar as funcionalidades dentro deles". Acredito que "funcionalidades" aqui se refira às definições. Se vc colocar as definições em um aquivo .h e incluir esse arquivo .h em vários fontes .c, para o mesmo projeto, o compilador irá acusar múltiplas definições para a mesma função

Comment: Isso aconteceria mesmo sem as funcionalidade, por isso que se deve colocar macros no começo do arquivo, `#ifndef` , `#if !defined()` ou `#pragma once`, isso fará com que não ocorra as múltiplas definições.

Comment: Não, acho que vc não me entendeu. O `#ifndef` , `#if !defined()` ou `#pragma once` evita que vc faça múltiplas inclusões no mesmo arquivo. Tipo, se vc tem um fonte que faz um include de arquivo x e y e o Y inclui novamente o x, essa diretivas protege isso. O que estou falando é de arquivos separados (fontes separadas, ou unidades de compilação distintas). Essas guardas não protege essas múltiplas definições.

Comment: certo, acho que entendi o que quis dizer, o fonte é importado para ambos os arquivos, mas se incluir em apenas um arquivo, não há problema, nesse ponto, não impede de usar dessa forma.

Comment: O uso de .h em apenas um .c é usado apenas em exemplos simples. Se aumentar a complexidade um pouco já começa a dar problema. Na verdade, o .h serve para separar a declaração de um nome de sua definição (.c) e evitar essas múltiplas redefinições que estou comentando.